# Remove leading uppercase char in a String with Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am struggling with another regex case at work. I need to be able to replace a beginning letter-char that is uppercaser. However, the touch is that I want to only be able to remove/replace this char as long as its the first and its standing by itself - What I mean is that it cannot stand next to another letter and be removed - It has to be the only uppercase letter in its space. In my code below I have managed to remove the first uppercase char - However my regex also removes "TH" which is essentially 2 chars which I dont want to remove. Any tips to adjust my regex?

```
    String test = "B, 02 abc";
    String test2= "TH - 2. tv";

    String works1 = test.replaceAll("^.*([A-Z])", "");
    String works2 =test2.replaceAll("^.*([A-Z])", "");

    System.out.println(works1);
    System.out.println(works2);
    
    //Desired result for works1 = ",02 abc"
    //Desired result for works2=  "TH- 2. tv"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^\\p{Lu}\\b", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k10Vqy/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\\p{Lu}`: Match any uppercase letter
- `\\b`: Word boundary

Note that if you want to allow optional non-word characters before uppercase letter then use:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^\\W*\\p{Lu}\\b", "");
```

Comment: - Thanks man. Your input is doing exactly as I intended! :D